# What could cause very slow (3 MB/s) disk access on a Ubuntu guest running under Hyper-V?

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, performance

I have a Ubuntu 11.10 x64 guest running under Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, configured according to [these directions](http://boinst.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/ubuntu-on-hyper-v/), including installation of the hyper-v modules. Network speed is fine (500 MB/s, measured with iperf), but disk access is laughable (3 MB/s, measured with dd).

What could possibly be causing this issue?

My other Ubuntu VMs have the same problem, my Windows VMs do not have this problem.

Comment: thanks for fixing my spelling @Jacob :) I've been spelling it "uBuntu" for years, but google tells me I'm pretty much alone in that. I wonder where I picked that up?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have the same issue with CentOS 6 after you install the integration tools?

Comment: I have not tried CentOS. I've only tried Ubuntu and Windows 7. I do need to run Ubuntu ultimately because it's part of a continuous integration process that needs to pass its unit tests and build ubuntu binaries for shipping. If installing a CentOS VM would help for diagnostic purposes I can do that, but I can't imagine how it would. My current best option is to convert the server to an ESXi host.

Comment: Are you using IDE or SCSI controllers for your virtual disks?

Comment: @Bigbio2002, the default: IDE. I'll switch it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Bigbio2002, the switch to SCSI is going to require a rebuild, so I'll report back tomorrow.

Comment: @Bigbio2002, that was quick: impossible to install ubuntu on hyper-V SCSI: "no disk drive was detected"

Comment: I believe you'd need the drivers that come with the VM additions for Linux.

Comment: what exact command are you running with dd?  i.e. block size?  /dev/zero or /dev/random for source?  Have you tried `hdparm` or `bonnie`?  The latter might give you something more to work with.

Comment: @gravyface: I'm running `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=4M count=1000`. I'll try `bonnie`.

Comment: @gravyface, here's the output from Bonnie [on an ESXi VM](http://pastebin.com/EwJjSvpn). The Hyper-V VM... well, it's still running the benchmark.

Comment: @gravyface, here's the output from Bonnie [on the Hyper-V VM](http://pastebin.com/RbJvmLuY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Hyper-V is just not that great for virtualising linux. Use [VMWare Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to convert the server to an ESXi image, install [ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html) on the server, then run the Windows machine as a VM. You can run the Ubuntu VMs as ESXi images with much better performance than you can get under Hyper-V.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this has been fixed, but at one point you had to enable the Hyper-V modules in  Ubuntu 10.04/2.6.x kernel (/etc/initramfs-tools/modules):

`hv_vmbus`

`hv_storvsc`

`hv_blkvsc`

`hv_netvsc`

Comment: Did that. Edited /etc/initramfs-tools/modules, did update-initramfs -u, rebooted, and confirmed modules were running with the command lsmod | grep hv_. Good suggestion though, that could be the cause for others with the same problem, thank you.

Comment: @Boinst did it fix the problem in any way?

Comment: @Nils, I followed these steps before posting my question. I will update the OP to note this fact.